# Convert binary string into two's complement

Tags: python, binary, twos-complement

For our homework assignemnt, we are asked to take in an integer and return the two's complement of it.

Currently, I am able to convert the integer into a binary string. From there, I know I need to invert the 0's and 1's and add 1 to the new string, but I do not know how to do that.

Could someone help me with that please?

```
def numToBinary(n):
    '''Returns the string with the binary representation of non-negative integer n.'''
    result = ''  
    for x in range(8):
        r = n % 2 
        n = n // 2
        result += str(r)

    result = result[::-1]
    return result

def NumToTc(n):
    '''Returns the string with the binary representation of non-negative integer n.'''
    binary = numToBinary(n)
    # stops working here
    invert = binary
    i = 0
    for digit in range(len(binary)):
        if digit == '0':
            invert[i] = '1'
        else:
            invert[i] = '0'
        i += 1
    return invert
```

***Note:*** This is an intro level course, so we are mainly stuck to using `loops` and `recursion`. We cannot really use any fancy formatting of strings, built-in functions, etc. beyond the basics.

Comment: Since this is an assignment - I feel I can only give a hint.  Look up your binary operations in the PHP manual.  Use the online manual. One of them will tell you how to do this.

Comment: At the risk of giving the assignment away, note that Python defines some very useful [bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)...

Comment: let me guess, you got a `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment` didn't you? please include the error messages you get when posting the question, it makes it **much** easier to help you with your actual problem.

Comment: @Liongold Thank you for that link. I was able to solve it.

Comment: @MarkManning Thank you for the insight. I was able to figure it out.

Comment: @jape: You are welcome! Have fun programming! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reach my solution by doing the following:

```
def numToBinary(n):
    '''Returns the string with the binary representation of non-negative integer n.'''
    result = ''  
    for x in range(8):
        r = n % 2 
        n = n // 2
        result += str(r)

    result = result[::-1]
    return result

def NumToTc(n):
    '''Returns the string with the binary representation of non-negative integer n.'''
    binary = numToBinary(n)
    for digit in binary:
        if int(digit) < 0:
            binary = (1 << 8) + n
    return binary
```

Comment: @Liongold I'm not quite sure I follow. Could you please show me an example, if you don't mind?